# Minimizing Log Likelihood in Python

Tags: python, excel, optimization, solver

This is a general question about optimisation in Python. The problem I am attempting to solve has 91 parameters which need to be optimised in order to minimise the log likelihood function. Currently, I am using `scipy.optimize.minimize`, however, I find the process is very slow, compared to using Excel's solver, despite my expectation that Python would be much faster.

Is this a case of `scipy.optimize.minimize` isn't as fast as Excel's Solver in general or is the number of parameters too great for scipy? And if so, is there an alternative to Excel's Solver in Python that would be faster?

Comment: Not an excel problem so why the tag?

Comment: Excel's nonlinear GRG solver is actually quite good and more sophisticated than `scipy.optimize.minimize`. Often a good starting point can help. Can you do standard LS regression to get decent estimates first?